# Why application is not responding to SetTimeout, android

Tags: android

I have assigned to a project. I have set timeout in device as 30 seconds (Settings -> Display -> Timeout ->30 seconds). But I found after 30 seconds my application is not dimmed means no effect of timeout. But when i created sample app in that app after 30 seconds my the screen dims. I am unable to understand why this is not happening in my project. I am neither using `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />` nor

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), 
                     Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, DELAY)
```

to work against LOCK.
Here are the list of permissions that i am using in my project. Can any one suggest me what are the possibility of this type of issue?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_OWNER_DATA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INPUT_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a USB cable plugged into the device, the device may stay awake based upon the Applications > Development > Stay Awake setting in the Settings application. Or, another application might be keeping the device awake with its own `WakeLock`.

BTW, that's a pretty extensive permission list. Be advised that many users will be put off by such a roster and may elect to not install your application as a result.